# Can Windows.UI.Input.Inking.dll be used with Visual Studio 2015 community, desktop edition?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, handwriting-recognition

I have tried for hours now to use a reference to `Windows.UI.Input.Inking.dll` on Windows 10 (64-bit) without success.

Can `Windows.UI.Input.Inking.dll` be used with Visual Studio 2015 community, desktop edition?

If so, how?

If it can't be used, what dll should be used for Windows 10 for handwriting recognition?

(I am currently using a Wacom tablet for ink gathering to my Windows 10 desktop computer. I wish to play with handwriting recognition within the `WPF context`).

> A reference to C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Input.Inking.dll could
>   not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that
>   it is a valid assembly or COM component.

TIA